# Add class based on URL not working with main url

Tags: jquery, class

I have the below code where the script checks for the li links and if that link is found within the url address a class get added and the sub ul will expand.

This works well on sub pages but on the root of the site all li's show slided down as if the url within the home link is not being detected. I think it has to do with the forward slash since the main page does not have it.

Any ideas?

```
$(function(){

var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
    // now grab every link from the navigation

    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
          $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).children('li').addClass('active');    
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).children('li').addClass('active');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }

      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp(50);
        checkElement.slideDown(800);
      }
      if($(this).children('li').find('ul').children().length ==0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;   
      }     
                }
            });



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an early return if urlRegExp is blank? Which it should be on your root path.

Assuming you don't want anything else to happen on your root page, then an

```
if(urlRegExp.length == 0){ 
  //root page 
} else { 
  //other page (what you are doing now)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added it to the answer :)